# MVC5 Url.Action showing RouteValues as QueryStrings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to have a custom route that use route values rather than query string, not sure why they are showing up as only query strings from a url action

Here is my route setup from my AreaRegistration

```
context.MapRoute(
  "Member_Bank_Account", 
  "Member/{controller}/{bank}/{account}", 
  new { action = "Index" }, 
  new[] { "Application.Web.Areas.Member.Controllers" });
```

And when I call it from html

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", 
                     "Bank", 
                      new {area = "Member", bank = "MyBank", account = "Primary"})"
                     class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Primary</a>
```

Both urls seems to work fine..

I can go to:

- http://localhost/Member/Bank/MyBank/Primary
- http://localhost/Member/Bank?bank=MyBank&account=Primary

But the html link always shows query string, not sure what i am doing wrong.

Any idea how to get it to show as a route instead of having query strings?

Comment: How is the controller action defined?

Comment: Which version of MVC? I see the links you're after in this demo project, which is MVC5: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m4aw9z9ew92j2av/WebApplication1.7z

Comment: Action is just a typical setup like this...  "public ActionResult Index(string bank, string account) { return this.View(); }"

Comment: It is using MVC v5.2.0

Comment: Provide your answer or delete the question? This is effectively clickbait...